# How to run LXC Ubuntu container on arm64 board

Tags: arm64, lxc

I need to run LXC Ubuntu container on my embedded board(ARM64).I used following command to create a ubuntu container.
lxc-create -n ubuntu01 -t /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-ubuntu --lxcpath=var/lib/lxc.
But when i execute the above command it shows some error as follows
ERROR:'debootstrap' command is missing
lxc-create: lxccontainer.c: create_run_template: 1290 container creation template for ubunt01 failed

### lxc-create: lxc_create.c: main: 316 Error creating container ubunt01

Required informations:
Kernel version:4.9.0
LXC version:2.0.0

Tried to execute as unprivileged container, but there is no change in the result.And before trying to execute on board, I have successfully created and executed the it on my linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, it's recommended to use the 'download' template to create containers, i.e.:

```
lxc-create -t download -n ubuntu01 -- -d ubuntu -r eoan -a arm64
```

This will download a pre-created container from the lxc image repository.  If you create it the way you are trying to do, then the ubuntu template is trying to create a new container from scratch.  So to make that work you would at least need to install debootstrap with:

```
apt-get install debootstrap
```